# Adicionar elementos dentro do Array condicionalmente em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Quando tento mesclar dois objetos usando o operador `spread` condicionalmente, ele funciona perfeitamente com as duas condiçôes `'true'` e `'false'`:

```js
let condition1 = false;
let condition2 = true;
let obj1 = {
  key1: 'value1'
};
let obj2 = {
  key2: 'value2',
  ...(condition1 && obj1),
};
let obj3 = {
  key3: 'value3'
};
let obj4 = {
  key4: 'value4',
  ...(condition2 && obj3),
};

console.log(obj2); // {key2: 'value2'}
console.log(obj4); // {key4: "value4", key3: "value3"}
```

**Quando tento usar a mesma lógica com `Arrays`, só funciona quando a condição é verdadeira `'true'`:**

```js
let condition = true;
let arr1 = ['value1'];
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(condition && arr1)];

console.log(arr2); // ['value2', 'value1']
```

**Se a condição for falsa `'false'`, um erro será lançado:**

```js
let condition = false;
let arr1 = ['value1'];
let arr2 = ['value2', ...(condition && arr1)];

console.log(arr2); // Error
```

**Por que o comportamento é diferente entre `Array` e `Object`?**

Comment: Executando seu código não gerou o erro, tente executar: https://es6console.com/jvrzeln3/

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser, curiosamente o código não gera nenhum erro no [es6console.com](https://es6console.com/jvrzeln3/), mas isso não resolve a questão porque em outros  ele navegadores/compiladores gera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

então vamos a explicação:

- Primeiro vamos entender as condicionais ternárias e lógicas:

  Bom, a condicional que você tentou implementar no seu código é a lógica, ou seja, ela verifica se uma determinada condição é satisfeita e só então realiza uma ação ou atribui um valor. No caso do lógico && acontece como se fosse um if, porém sem o else e caso a condição não seja satisfeita ele retornará undefined, experimente:

```js
// Lógico &&
// condição && se true
console.log('Lógico &&');

let cond = false;

const valueUndef = cond && 'teste'; // undefined/false

cond = true;

const valueDef = cond && 'teste'; // 'teste'

console.log(valueUndef);
console.log(valueDef);

// Ternário ?
// condição ? se true : se false
console.log('Ternário ?');

cond = false;

const valueDefOrUndef1 = cond ? 'cond true' : 'cond false';

cond = true;

const valueDefOrUndef2 = cond ? 'cond true' : 'cond false';

console.log(valueDefOrUndef1);
console.log(valueDefOrUndef2);
```

- Agora veremos o motivo de funcionar em objetos literais e não em arrays:

  Bom, primeiro você precisa saber que apesar de ambos serem objetos, tem comportamentos distintos e também reagem de forma distinta ao spread, isso por que enquanto o spread em um array espera receber um elemento iterable(String, Array, TypedArray, Map e Set) o spread em um objeto literal apenas espera receber um objeto qualquer e utiliza internamente das funcionalidade Object.values, Object.keys e/ou Object.entries para capturar as props e values daquele objeto para incorporá-lo. Exemplos:

```js
// Objeto literal

const obj1 = { k1: 1 };
const obj2 = { k2: 2 };
const obj3 = { k3: 3 };
const obj4 = { k4: 4 };

const obj5 = { k5: 5, ...(true && obj1), ...(false && obj2) }

console.log(obj5);

// Internamente o que aconteceu aqui foi mais ou menos isso:

const obj3Keys = Object.keys(obj3);
const obj3Values = Object.values(obj3);

obj3Keys.forEach((v, i) => {
  obj4[v] = obj3Values[i];
});

console.log(obj4);

/* Ao receber o false como retorno da operação lógica e tentar
pegar suas props e values ele simplesmente retornou um iterable
vazio pois este objeto não tem props e values legíveis. */

console.log(Object.keys(false));
console.log(Object.values(false));

/* Sendo assim o spread funcionou como deveria para o objeto
mesmo não passando na condição, pois tentou espalhar o iterable
vazio e obviamente não incrementou nenhuma prop ou value por
conta deste fato. */

// Array

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
const arr3 = [...(true && arr1)];
console.log(arr3);

const arr4 = [...(false && arr2)];
console.log(arr4);

/* Utilizando a operação lógica neste caso você tem um efeito
inesperado, na primeira situação para o caso true tudo deve
correr normalmente, porém na segunda situação para o caso false
devemos ter um erro dizendo que não foi possível iterar sobre o
elemento estipulado. */
```

- Entendendo o que ocorreu...

  Isso acontece por que o spread no array espera receber um objeto exclusivamente iterável(String, Array, TypedArray, Map e Set) e vai buscar por uma propriedade única de cada array e oculta chamada Symbol.iterator para utilizar dela para iterar sobre a estrutura. Como os objetos geralmente retornados na negação da operação lógica são false; undefined e null, então eles não são iteráveis, o que acaba resultando no erro de sistema. Isso pode ser facilmente resolvido com uma operação lógica composta ou com o próprio ternário. Exemplos:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2];
const arr2 = [3, 4];

const arr3 = [...(false && arr1 || [5, 6])];

console.log(arr3);
/* Retornou false na primeiro operação, porém por ser uma
operação composta com uma alternativa or(||) eu consegui enviar outro elemento para ser iterado. */

const arr4 = [...(false ? arr2 : [])];

console.log(arr4);
/* Aqui da mesma forma retornou false, porém utlizando o ternário
eu pude gerar uma alternativa vazia para a condição, para que
tudo corresse normalmente mas nenhum valor fosse adicionado. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```js
let conditional = false;
let arr4 = ['value2', ...(condition ? arr1 : [])];
```

Comment: Te importas de editar o código para ele funcionar e também explicar porquê essa solução.